# Why my locale in HttpServletResponse is always en_US?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, locale

I'm using **Spring MVC** as our controller framework, to implement our app internationalization, I use `org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor` to detect language change, and I hope system's default language will be set as user client's locale if no specific language is set. Now I encountered a stranger problem during setting the default locale, I came from China, locale is zh_CN by default, when our system is deployed on Windows server, I can get the correct locale (`zh_CN`) from `HttpServletResponse`, but when our system deployed on Ubuntu Linux server, I always get `en_US` locale from `HttpServletResponse`. I just confused about that, we know `HttpServletResponse's` locale comes from clients like Web browser, 2 requests come from the same locale, but appear 2 different locales in `HttpServletResponse`.

Thanks, I's wondering if any guys who have ever occurred and eventually solved this problem.

Comment: 1. Try `locale` on your ubuntu server check the system configuration, if it is en_US, change it to whatever you want, here is a link as reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89976/how-to-change-the-default-locale-in-ubuntu-10-10-server

Comment: Thanks!!! @Jaiwo99 I don't want to set to any specific language, I just want HttpServletResponse's default locale comes from client, not comes from linux's configuration. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Then like @taringamberini said, use `CookieLocaleResolver`

Comment: @Jaiwo99 I'm using CookieLocaleResolver which doesn't solve my default language problem.

Comment: Then post your config please

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a `CookieLocaleResolver` too?

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
</bean>
<mvc:interceptors>     
    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale">
        <bean  class="java.util.Locale">
            <constructor-arg value="zh" />
            <constructor-arg value="CN" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**UPDATE**

Does your pages declare?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="zh-CN" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the same configuration as yours.

Comment: Thanks again!! @taringamberini I just want HttpServletResponse's default locale comes from client, not comes from any other configuration. Right now I'm attempting to explicitly set language with JavaScript.

Comment: @BradyChu If you look at [CookieLocaleResolver.java source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/1.2.3/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/CookieLocaleResolver.java) you can see that the locale is detected from the request: so you should enforce the right locale starting from the browser and ending on the web application server.

Comment: @BradyChu You should understand what is your web application server default strategy in getting the locale and, if the default is getting locale from current java process (or similar), how to configure your web application server to get the locale from header request.